# IE 8 Temporary Internet Files not created when using Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp

What would prevent Temporary Internet Files from being created/written in Windows 7 to the:

```
    C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\
```

I have come across a situation and I am not sure where to look for a possible solution, so I will try and best describe what is happening.

Two test machines are as follows:

1. Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 w/Internet Explorer 8 (ver. 8.0.7601.17514 32 or 64bit)
2. Windows XP SP3 w/Internet Explorer 8 (ver. 8.0.6001.18702CO 32bit)

Two Websites are as follows:

1. Production Website exists in the same Domain as Machine #1 & #2

   ```
   (http://prod.mysite/myApp/)
   ```
2. Development Website exists in a Cloud environment with a different domain

   ```
   (http://dev.cloud/myApp/)
   ```

Issue I am seeing is:
Accessing Website #1 from using system #1 (Windows 7) will result in Temporary Internet Files being created in the location below.

```
    C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\
```

However if I access Website #2 from system #1 (Windows 7) ***NO*** files are created.

Accessing Website #1 or #2 from system #2 (Windows XP) files are created as expected.

What I am looking or is direction on where I should be looking to find the cause, given that it only happens on Windows 7 with a website in a different domain.  Is it a GPO? an Internet Explorer 8 Privacy or Security setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows creates them in a hidden folder **LOW** under Temporary Internet Files.

[image]

This happens because of the UAC/LowIL (http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/magazine/2007.06.uac%28en-us%29.aspx). Programs with LOW IL can only write into folder with low IL. Because IE runs with LowIL (Sandbox) there files are created there.

Comment: I have just checked on System #1 (Windows 7) and it does indeed contain a **LOW** directory, but there are no contents in it.  Is it possible that the restrictions are high enough that it doesn't even allow the creation at the **LowIL** level?

Comment: Have you configured Windows to show the content of hidden folders?

Comment: If I look below into the **Content.IE5** directory I see four sub-directories that contain temporary files.  There is no _Internet Address_ column option available in Window Explorer so I can't confirm that they are from site #2 even though they most likely are.  This definitely gives me enough to do some more through testing. Thank You